# Mocking child functions in unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, integration-testing

How do you mock standalone functions in Golang? Let me use an example to explain.

### Example (Written in Golang)

Suppose you have some code like this:

```
type Item struct {
    price            int
    initialFee       int
    initialDiscounts int
    initialTax       int
}

func calculateCost(item Item) int {
    finalDiscounts := calculateFinalDiscounts(item.initialDiscounts)
    finalFee := calculateFinalFee(item.initialFee)
    finalTax := calculateFinalTax(item.initialTax)

    finalCharges := finalFee + finalTax
    if finalCharges > 15 {
        finalCharges = 15
    }

    cost := sumCost(item.price, finalDiscounts, finalCharges)

    if cost > 100 {
        return 100
    }

    return cost
}


func calculateFinalDiscounts(initialDiscounts int) int {
    if initialDiscounts > 10 {
        return initialDiscounts
    }

    return 0
}

func calculateFinalFee(initialFee int) int {
    if initialFee > 10 {
        return initialFee
    }

    return 0
}

func calculateFinalTax(initialTax int) int {
    if initialTax > 10 {
        return initialTax
    }

    return 0
}

func sumCost(price, finalDiscounts, finalCharges int) int {
    return price - finalDiscounts + finalCharges
}
```

### Questions

1. Let's assume each of the `calculateFinalXXX` functions have their own unit tests. Suppose you want to write a unit test for the `calculateCost` function, should you be testing all 8 permutations of different values of discounts, fee and tax (where the value is value above/below 10)? Or should you only test logic within the scope of the function (eg. the logic relating to `finalCharges > 15`), since the individual functions already have unit tests of their own?
2. How can we test the `calculateCost` function independently (in an isolated manner)?

Regarding question 2, we would need to somehow "mock" the individual functions `calculateFinalFee`, `calculateFinalDiscounts`, and `calculateFinalTax`. But you can't really do this in Golang. If you wanted to test the logic for `finalCharges > 15` (whcih exists in the `calculateCost` function), you would need to manually craft your Item struct such that this condition is met. But I feel that this is not maintainable. Why? Because if either the `calculateFinalFee` or the `calculateFinalTax` function changes its implementation (eg. capping the fee to 100 instead of 10), you would need to update the Item struct accordingly. Also, what if these child functions are more complex? It may not be trivial to manually craft an item struct just so you can get a specific value. Alternatively, if there was a way to mock these functions, you could mock the response from `calculateFinalFee` and `calculateFinalTax`, and test the `calculateCost` function independently (regardless of the logic in `calculateFinalFee` and `calculateFinalTax`). But mocking standalone functions is not possible in Golang.

I understand that the better implementation would be to implement the individual `calculateFinalXXX` functions under an Interface, and perhaps take that Interface as a parameter instead. For example:

```
type Calculator interface {
    calculateFinalDiscounts(int) int
    calculateFinalFee(int) int
    calculateFinalTax(int) int
}

func calculateCost(item Item, calc Calculator) int {
    finalDiscounts := calc.calculateFinalDiscounts(item.initialDiscounts)
    finalFee := calc.calculateFinalFee(item.initialFee)
    finalTax := calc.calculateFinalTax(item.initialTax)

    ...
}
```

By doing so, you can mock the return values of that Interface. **But surely this can't be the solution for everything?** If the solution is always "just convert it to an Interface", this would mean that you simply cannot write any individual standalone functions in your codebase, as there would be no way to mock them and write proper tests for their parent functions. Some functions could simply be very small utility functions, and it feels like an overkill if you expose every small function as an Interface so that you can mock them during testing. There must be a better way to do this, but I don't see how...

And even if you did pass an Interface into the `calculateCost` function, how would you assert that the `finalCharges` indeed caps to 15 unless you also mock the `sumCost` function and assert the input parameter? At the end of the day, to write a properly isolated unit test, it seems like you would need to be using Interfaces everywhere and for every single function call. Is this truly the best approach?

Note: I understand that the code perhaps could be refactored such that the logic for `finalChanges > 15` exists elsewhere, but for the sake of the example, let's suppose that the `calculateCost` function is indeed the best place where this logic should exist.

Comment: "Should you be testing all 8 permutations of different values of discounts, fee and tax?" That's what I would do. See https://dave.cheney.net/2019/05/07/prefer-table-driven-tests That fact that calculateCost calls a few trivial functions is an Implementation detail. The functions are so trivial, in fact, that it's not clear what you would even replace them with. Don't overthink.

Comment: You don’t mock this type of things or just provide them through a variable.

Comment: @Volker I understand I could possibly provide them through a variable, but feels like this can't always be the solution? This would mean you would need to pass every function as a variable if you really wanted to write isolated tests. My main goal is really to figure out what are the best practices when it comes to situations like these (where it may not be feasible to pass a variable). This need for mocking standalone functions feels like a common need, but there doesn't seem to be any solution.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what‘s the intended meaning of „unit“ and „isolation“ during testing.

Comment: hi @Volker, ignoring the terminology, I'm trying to explore how we can possibly test the calculateCost in a way that does not depend on the implementation of its dependency functions - calculateFinalDiscounts, calculateFinalFee, etc (this is what i mean by "isolation", but whether this terminology is correct or not doesn't actually matter, the important thing is whether we can achieve this in a practical way without having to pass all these dependency functions as a variable. Is this simply a limitation of Golang? Do other languages provide better ways of doing this?).

Comment: "how we can possibly test the calculateCost in a way that does not depend on the implementation of its dependency functions" I see no point in this undertaking. Maybe Go (that's the correct spelling of the language's name) is not for you.

Comment: @Volker "I see no point in this undertaking" - I feel it does make sense to want to test a function solely based on the logic within the function, while mocking any return values of its dependency functions. After all, I suppose the unit test should test the logic of the function, and not of its child functions (otherwise for every ancestor function, you would need to test the functionality of all its child functions) - which is also why we have dependency injection and mocking of interfaces. But I can see how this might just be impossible in Go.

Comment: Look @Ryn you have a certain idea of what unittesting should look like and how it should be done etc. All this doesn't match mine where "child functions" are an implementation detail that doesn't matter. I understand what you think and I think it's just wrong, so we won't agree.

Comment: @Volker would like to understand your perspective as well. How would you go about testing a high-level function that has many "descendent" functions? Would you test all the permutations of every single "descendent" function, even if it means possibly hundreds of permutations (since every new if statement would possibly double the permutations)? Also, would you repeat the exact same test cases for each of the "descendant" functions? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Of course. If you want to test what a function does and if there are 50 different ways the function can behave (either because the function itself is complicated or the behaviour of what you call descendent functions varies) you have to test 50 cases. Fortunately this doesn't come up in practice often.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make some table-driven tests to test the calculateFinalXxx and the sumCost functions with a few sensible test parameters:

```golang
func Test_calculateFinalFee(t *testing.T) {
    testCases := []struct {
        fee  int
        want int
    }{
        {11, 11},
        {10, 0},
        {9, 0},
    }

    for _, tc := range testCases {
        got := calculateFinalFee(tc.fee)
        if got != tc.want {
            t.Errorf("calculateFinalFee(%d) = %d; want %d", tc.fee, got, tc.want)
        }
    }

}

func Test_calculateFinalDiscounts(t *testing.T) {
    testCases := []struct {
        discounts int
        want      int
    }{
        {11, 11},
        {10, 0},
        {9, 0},
    }

    for _, tc := range testCases {
        got := calculateFinalDiscounts(tc.discounts)
        if got != tc.want {
            t.Errorf("calculateFinalDiscounts(%d) = %d; want %d", tc.discounts, got, tc.want)
        }
    }

}

func Test_calculateFinalTax(t *testing.T) {
    // ...
}

func Test_sumCost(t *testing.T) {
    testCases := []struct {
        price     int
        discounts int
        charges   int
        want      int
    }{
        {10, 0, 0, 10},  // no discounts, no charges, cost is just price
        {10, 1, 1, 10},  // discounts == charges, cost is just price
        {10, 1, 0, 9},   // with just a discount
        {10, 0, 1, 11},  // with just a charge
    }

    for _, tc := range testCases {
        p, d, c := tc.price, tc.discounts, tc.charges
        got := sumCost(p, d, c)
        if got != tc.want {
            t.Errorf("sumCost(price:%d, discounts:%d, charges:%d) = %d; want %d", p, d, c, got, tc.want)
        }
    }
}
```

Then add your calculateCost test, and test.